# h:panelGrid that looks like rich:dataTabale

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm faced with task of coding a table with RichFaces, but this table is not a regular table where you have variable number of uniform rows of data. It has constant set of rows, and each row has different logic for different columns. Each row has a corresponding property in mbean.

So it would be clearer to embed these rows directly into the view instead of overcomplicating things by wrapping properties into the collection, adding some flags, and stuffing them into the `rich:dataTable`.

It would be perfect to use `h:panelGrid`, if it weren't that it looks different than `rich:dataTable`. The problem is that although it does contain `columnClasses` attribute, which allows me to create a near resemblance of `rich:dataTable` body using `rich-table-cell` CSS class, it does not allow me to reproduce header cells. `h:panelGrid` just doesn't have a mechanism to style separate cells differently, so I cannot style top row of cells as table header.

So the question is, is it possible to achiev look and feel of `rich:dataTable` with `h:panelGrid` or am I just wasting my time? Any suggestions are really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I might consider using ui:repeat and just iterate over data as tr elements -- customizing what you need to customize. Or in your case, I might just manually construct the table since it's a fixed number of rows with unique requirements for each row/cell.

h:panelGrid is a great component when you have a uniform structure but is difficult to utilize for complex layouts.